# Can hot tap water touching rainwater frozen by winter create a valid mikveh?

Tags: halacha, water, mikvah-ritual-bath

I'm considering building an outside mikveh, with the freshwater section above the rainwater section (with two holes between them, classical "bor al gabai bor" halachic design) but there is no realistic way to keep the rainwater bottom 'bor' liquid during winter.  However, it would not be difficult to fill the top section with warm fresh water.  Will the slight ice melt of the bottom rainwater section by the top water section be considered sufficient mixing to create a valid mikveh in winter?

Comment: Can you [edit] in a diagram? That might help people understand the case better.

Comment: See ShA YD 201:30

Comment: Very good question!

Comment: @DoubleAA I think that can there is an additional problem: if the frozen Mikve is mamash frozen as a glass and it is impossible theoretically to tovel betocho, may be that it is not a Mikve, so , hashaka is not helpfull.

Comment: I am not sure that contact between solid an d liquid matters may be called Hashaka. I am not sure at 100% but it seem's not reglemantary

Answer (score 1):

Yd 201.75.
Can not do kiss (connection) if the 2 waters are different (temperature)

---

Think you might want to know

Yd201.31.
If collected water (not rain water) is frozen and then melted it stops being considered connected

Comment: Yshar Coach Can you quote the halachot, I do not find

Comment: יֵשׁ מִי **שֶׁאוֹסֵר** לְהַטִּיל יוֹרָה מְלֵאָה מַיִם חַמִּין לְתוֹךְ **וְכֵן לְמַלֹּאת מִקְוֶה מַיִם חַמִּין וּלְחַבְּרוֹ  לְנָהָר בִּשְׁפוֹפֶרֶת הַנּוֹד**    now i see that i may be wrong with this but I still remember that if the 2 waters are . different there is no hashoko  31 מִקְוֶה שָאוּב שֶׁהִגְלִיד, טָהוֹר מִשּׁוּם מַיִם שְׁאוּבִים. נִמּוֹחוּ, כָּשֵׁר לְהִקָּווֹת.

Comment: @kouty See above